# Visual Studio 2015 - Change template for new applicationHost.config

Tags: iis-express, visual-studio-2015

Unlike previous versions, [Visual Studio 2015 places build-related files in a .vs folder alongside your solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/07/21/visual-studio-2015-rtm-what-s-new-in-the-ide.aspx#VSFolder).  By default, that includes a new applicationHost.config for web applications.

As stated [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4341a873-2ae8-4ded-878c-1cbd74c599ba/useglobalapplicationhostfile-property?forum=msbuild), You can edit the web application .csproj/.vbproj file to include `<UseGlobalApplicationHostFile>True</UseGlobalApplicationHostFile>`, and then it will continue to use %userprofile%\My Documents\IISExpress\config\ApplicationHost.config

But I don't want to change every web application project file.  So is there a "template" for the new applicationHost.config that Visual Studio / IIS Express creates?

Comment: Is this the best solution when loading a webforms app created in vs2013 in vs2015? Is there a cleaner way of doing this rather than telling the csproj files to all use the applicationhost.config file in the Documents folder that vs2013 used.

Comment: Why do you want to do that ? Because of overrideModeDefault="Deny" in the security/authentication settings ?

Comment: @frenchone, yes, that's exactly the scenario I was looking to address.

Answer (score 13):

You can edit the template that Visual Studio uses at %ProgramFiles(x86)%\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer\applicationhost.config